# Spring Boot Data Starter cannot automatically generate DDL with invalid liquibase configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.0.2.RELEASE`. The database is H2 (embedded).

I have defined some `@Entity` classes in my `@SpringBoot` application. `spring.data.generate-ddl` is turned on and `spring.data.hibernate.ddl-auto` is `create-drop`. However, on application startup, the following exception occurred:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find changelog location: class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] (please add changelog or check your Liquibase configuration)
```

Only after I added the liquibase changelog could the application start and database work properly. Why would this happen? Shouldn't Spring Boot already take care of the DDL? How should I configure my Spring Boot app to remove the step to write db changelogs?

application.properties:

```
server.port=8888
logging.level.root=INFO

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
```

dependencies:

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$spring_boot_version"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:$spring_boot_version"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:$spring_boot_version"
compile 'com.h2database:h2:2.1.210'
compile 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
```

Comment: Please, share the list of dependencies you're using. And a property file as well

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to the hint from @htshame, the cause is dependency leak from other modules in my project. According to [spring's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-liquibase-database-migrations-on-startup), the migration is automatically run when `spring-boot-starter-liquibase` is present (Although I'm not depending on spring's liquibase solution directly, there are liquibase packages leaked out)

To disable liquibase, in `application.properties`, add:

```
spring.liquibase.enabled=false
```